# Going to start project on android

Tags: android, xml, json, xml-parsing

Im gonna start a project on android.
It will be car selling.

1st, which libraries do I need for interface? Functionality I need is
1)Images in grid blocks on whole screen.
2)Images zooming.

And 2nd, I have to connect my app with xml or json file that will contains cars with infos and image. The server that will output xml (or json) file with cars is already done.

How I could parse that xml and json? The easiest way to connect that base to app?

Comment: [Huh](https://www.google.com/)?

Comment: The best thing about this post is @codeMagic ability to include a link in a comment.

Comment: Ive searched enough. Have a lot infos. But I need help to get right way. To use good and useful libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the grid you can use the standard GridView included in the SDK. To load images, I like to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and for out of the box pinch to zoom and double tap zoom I use [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView).

To retrieve and create the JSON object you can use [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley) or [AsyncHttpClient](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). You can also use Volley for the image loading, but I find Picasso a little more convenient.

Unless there's already a client built for your particular web service, you will have to parse the JSON or XML yourself, using appropriate classes from the SDK (look up JSONObject and XMLPullParser).

I hope that answers your questions.

Comment: huh, there's a good man that understood what I need. Thank you. Useful for me. Which lib is good for blocks? for example on page there'are many blocks with main image and caption.